# How pimcore routes work?

Tags: php, zend-framework, pimcore

I am trying to use pimcore but i am stuck with routes.

Still their is not so much detailed documentation on routes how to create & use them.
I also want to create URL like http://www.example.com/controller/action but i did not get any way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Controllers/Actions are handled by documents in Pimcore. Just asign a controller and action to a document and the route will be generated by Pimcore.

It is explained in the documentation: [Documents](http://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE/Documents)

On the other hand, you can use magic parameters to access to a controller/action directly:

```
/?controller=myController&action=myAction
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create routes for your controller action then you have open your pimcore admin.

In that your home url is shown, right click on the home in Documents panel 'Add Page'.

A new tab is opend with name home, in that you have to go for settings panel.

In settings panel you can specify your Controller, Action, Path(your route), key(your key name for that Action).

So the url will be shown as (home path)/(key name)